# Interactive faceted rCharts bar graph filled with a third variable (replicate ggplot2 aes(x=var1, fill=var2) + geom_bar + facet_wrap)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, rcharts, slidify

I want to make an interactive bar chart of one variable where the bars are filled in by a second variable and faceted by a third variable. I would like to embed it in a slidify deck. I am guessing rCharts is the right tool for this (or would another package be better?).

Here is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(numbers = rep(1:3, 30),
                 letter = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 90, replace = TRUE),
                 status = sample(c("good", "bad", "ugly"), 90, replace = TRUE))
```

I can do this in ggplot2, but I can't make it interactive. I can make this graph (sorry, can't embed):

```
ggplot(df, aes(letter, fill = status)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(.~numbers)
```

[image: Linked chart]

Ideally I would be able to select and deselect "status" and see the bars change. I've played with the bar chart code on [this page](https://rpubs.com/dnchari/rcharts) but can't make it work. Is this functionality possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're after in ggplot? I couldn't tell if you wanted a ggplots solution or rCharts solution. So this is ggplot.

Add position = "dodge" to your geom_bar argument will mimic the other graph you linked to

```
ggplot(df, aes(letter, fill = status)) +
 geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
 facet_wrap(.~numbers)
```

Alternatively, you could "unselect" status, and fill by number -- note, had to make this a factor in this example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(letter, fill = as.factor(numbers))) +
 geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
 facet_wrap(.~numbers)
```

Or omit and keep grayscale

```
ggplot(df, aes(letter)) +
 geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
 facet_wrap(.~numbers)
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want an rCharts solution because I would like it to be interactive. I edited my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I was a heavy `rCharts` user, but nowadays, in my opinion, `plotly` is a better supported option (`rCharts` is not in CRAN anymore).

Furthermore`plotly` has an automatic way to make `ggplot2` charts interactive. For your example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(
  numbers = rep(1:3, 30),
  letter = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 90, replace = TRUE),
  status = sample(c("good", "bad", "ugly"), 90, replace = TRUE)
)

p <-
  ggplot(df, aes(letter, fill = status)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(. ~ numbers)

ggplotly(p)
```

**EDIT 1**

This edit is made to suit the needs of the comment. 
The changes you requested cannot be made directly from `ggplot2` so you need to use `plotly`. There may be a more elegant way to do the chart than my for loops but they seem to work:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
# make data.table
df <- data.table(
  numbers = rep(1:3, 30),
  letter = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 90, replace = TRUE),
  status = sample(c("good", "bad", "ugly"), 90, replace = TRUE)
)


# keep unique status values for bars and numbers for facets
traces <- df[,unique(status)]
facets <- df[,unique(numbers)]
# cast df
casted_df <- dcast(df,letter + numbers ~ status )
# initialise list to keep charts   
facetplots <- list()
for(i in 1:length(facets)){
  # initialise chart
  facetplots[[i]] <- plot_ly(type = "bar")
  facet_df <- casted_df[numbers == facets[i]]
  for(j in traces){
    if(i == 1){
      facetplots[[i]] <- add_trace(facetplots[[i]], x = facet_df[,letter], y = facet_df[,get(j)],legendgroup = j , color = j, name = j )

    }else{
      facetplots[[i]] <- add_trace(facetplots[[i]], x = facet_df[,letter], y = facet_df[,get(j)],legendgroup = j, color = j , name = j ,  showlegend = F)

    }
  }
  facetplots[[i]] <- layout(  facetplots[[i]], barmode = "stack")
}

q <- subplot(facetplots, shareX = TRUE)

q
```

Comment: I was just hoping for a functionality where I could select and deselect "good", "bad", and "ugly", and the bars would automatically adjust themselves. I can show and hide the different categories--but the bars themselves do not change (so if I deselect the category in the middle of the bars, the top of the bars remain hovering over it rather than the bars morphing).